# How to always open google plus login screen in Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-plus

I am adding Google+ Login in my app. Its working fine with Safari in simulator.
On button click its opening safari and when user done login came back to app.

But when i am testing it on device which has google chrome its open in it. and does not came back to app after login.

So is there way to display google plus login in safari only instead of chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Official documentation of G+.](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in)

> It provides single sign-on via the Google+ app (if installed), Chrome for iOS (if installed), or Mobile Safari.

**So is there way to display google plus login in safari only instead of chrome.**
-> May be you need to remove/uninstall app of goole chrome from you iOS device.